# Exception when playing random song from my array list on shake

Tags: ios, audio, shake

I am developing an app which plays a random song on device shake. Following is my code

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var player = AVAudioPlayer()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func motionEnded(_ motion: UIEventSubtype, with event: UIEvent?) {
        if event?.subtype == UIEventSubtype.motionShake{
            let soundArray=["firstsong","second","fourth"]
            let randomNumber=Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(Int32(soundArray.count))))

            let fileLocation = Bundle.main.path(forResource: soundArray[randomNumber], ofType: "mp3")
            do {
                try player=AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf:URL(fileURLWithPath:fileLocation!))
                player.play()
            }catch{

            }
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

I have placed my mp3 files in music folder.
When i shake the device i get the following error

```
Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Ok, you need to debug your code.  break it into small steps with local variables, set a breakpoint at the top of the function, and then step through it, examining the results of each line. My money is on the expression `fileLocation!`. If fileLocation is nil, that will crash. (I call the force-unwrap operator the "crash if nil" operator. You should avoid it until you really know what you're doing.)

Answer (score 0):

Wait. You said you placed the files in your music folder? Your code is wrong then. The code you posted tries to read the files from inside your app bundle. You need to use a different approach entirely to read files from the user's music folder, and need to write that code to check to see if the file exists and fail gracefully if not.

I suggest dragging your sound files into the "resources" folder in your project in Xcode, and making sure the checkbox for the files is checked so that they are included in your app bundle. If you do that your code should work (but you should still check for nil rather than using force unwrapping, as mentioned in my comment above.)

Comment: Note that you should really use `url(forResource:withExtension:)` rather than `path(forResource:ofType:)`. Apple is moving away from using path strings and URL-based methods are preferred for new development. (On Mac OS you HAVE to use URL based methods to get sandboxing to work correctly.)